# Instagram graphql hides "count" in "edge_hashtag_to_media"

Tags: java, web-scraping, instagram-graph-api

I'm looking for the posts count of an hashtag using the "?__a=1" Instagram open API.
I'm using Java. I make a GET request to the endpoint "https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/cachorro/?__a=1", store the response to a *JSONObject* and get the posts count in this way:

```
object.getJSONObject("graphql").getJSONObject("hashtag").getJSONObject("edge_hashtag_to_media").getInt("count")
```

When I execute the code on my development PC, I get the right value:

```
{
   "count": 8546301,
   "page_info": {
      "has_next_page": true,
      "end_cursor": "QVFCVHpDLTR4RHNUMjVPN1FOQk03QXpKWWRwYnk3ZjZJek5uOEdfczNYcWJiOWtSU3VIbEtuUzMwN01KSDYwaGs1eWJ0WUVrSWVjR3RMeEFfTTB1S1NRQw=="
   }...
```

When the code is executed on my VPS server, I get an empty value:

```
{"count":0,"page_info":{"has_next_page":false,"end_cursor":null},"edges":[]}
```

I'm using *HttpURLConnection* with all the cookies needed by Instagram:

```
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
InstagramCookieBuilder cookieBuilder = new InstagramCookieBuilder();
InstagramCookie cookie = cookieBuilder.igDid("HIDDEN")
                                            .mid("HIDDEN")
                                            .shbid("HIDDEN")
                                            .shbts("HIDDEN")
                                            .sessionId("HIDDEN")
                                            .rur("HIDDEN")
                                            .csrfToken("HIDDEN")
                                            .dsUserId("HIDDEN")
                                            .urlGen("\"{\"VPS_IP_ADDRESS\": HIDDEN\HIDDEN\"VPS_MAC_ADDRESS\": HIDDEN}:HIDDEN\"")
                                            .build();
String cookieString = cookie.toString();
con.setRequestProperty("Cookie", cookieString);
```

What is wrong?